How to save in development Power Automate Cloud flow? Comment out sections?
Does anyone know how to get Power Automate Cloud to allow saving a flow that is incomplete? Right now, every time I try to save it tells me there are errors and refuses to let me save. I understand there are errors since it is still a work in progress.
One potential solution would be to comment out sections of the code with the error, or comment out the entire flow (similar to what you can do in Ui Path); however, I don't see that option either. How to comment out sections of code?
After googling I haven't found a solution to either of these. Any one have any ideas?

It is what it is, just put some dummy stuff in to make it save. There are no other options.

I prefer using the parent-child flows method. You can make a simple parentflow, and the heavy calculating stuff is outsourced to the child flows.
